# Issue with SQL statement with joins on a double aliased table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was not sure how to title this issue, below is an example of what I want to do which is create two values of a total of something above a threshold and one for below but the two statements are exclusive of one another. I thought using a left join or left out join might work. Any ideas please?

```
SELECT Count(Sale1.id) above500, 
       Count(sale2.id) below500, 
       employee.name 
FROM   employeesale es 
       INNER JOIN employee 
               ON es.employeeid = employee.id 
       LEFT JOIN sale Sale1 
              ON es.saleid = sale1.id 
       LEFT JOIN sale Sale2 
              ON es.saleid = sale2.id 
WHERE  Sale1.value >= 500 
       AND Sale2.value < 500
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results. The query is wrong and trying to reverse engineer what results you were trying to get will be, well, trying.

Comment: So this is not valid SQL Server syntax since there is no `GROUP BY` - have you **actually** tried anything yet?  I don't think this code has even been run in SSMS since it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Perhaps some sample data and a desired result set would help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need both joins.  Do a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sum(case when sale.value >= 500 then 1 else 0 end) as above500, 
       sum(case when sale.value < 500 then 1 else 0 end) as below500, 
       employee.name 
FROM   employeesale es 
       INNER JOIN employee 
               ON es.employeeid = employee.id 
       LEFT JOIN sale
              ON es.saleid = sale.id 
group by employee.name
```

I added the `group by` clause.  Also, you don't seem to need the employeesale table, unless you are using it for filtering purposes.